# TwentyFourteen Theme : Changing grid layout

Tags: themes, css, html

I have been plugging away making my new site and it is going great with only one issue so far.

How would I go about changing the featured posts grid so that instead of displaying 3 featured posts per row, it will display either two featured posts per row or four (either will work).

Any help on how to accomplish this would be amazing!
Thanks again!

Comment: Try reading this which might help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/featured-content-limited-to-6-possible-to-randomize

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - had to change the container to hold image widths of 24.9% or 50% depending on layout, remove the clear from both post divs and stretch the .site width to 100%. From there I had either 4 horizontal images or two x two set-up. If anyone has any questions about this feel free to ask.